# Problems with audio on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

I recently installed Arch Linux  with Plasma 5 and I'm having some sound problems.

I have 2 sound output devices on my PC, a sound card and my HDMI port on my graphics card, when i connect the PC to my TV, it plays the sound on the sound card and when I plug in my headphones, it plays the sound on my TV.

How can I adjust/fix this?

Comment: Assuming you are running Pulseaudio, try setting the sound sink you want in `pavucontrol`.

Comment: I changed some configurations on pavucontrol, but i can't get it to switch the output device automatically when i plug in my headphones.

Comment: There's the `Auto-Mute Mode` control (see `amixer contents`) that can switch between speaker and headphones *one the same card* by muting one device. If you normally play sound on your TV and want it automatically to switch to headphones if you plug them in, you'll have to write some kind of program that watches for the event and does this for you. Run `evtest` as root, it will tell you on which `/dev/input/eventX` to listen for the plug-in event. If you can't program, it may be easier to just manually switch.